# Can a column be referenced from multiple table as a foreign key

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key

Suppose I have a table named `Service`.
But I have other tables that have a similarities with that table
like `RoomService`, `ConsultatonService`, etc.

Can the `Id` of `RoomService` and `ConsultationService` keep a foreign key reference to `Service` table's `ServiceId` column but being identifiable by the `Type` column in the `Service` table?

[image: Many association in a single fieldstrong text]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. Your `services` table will store all the common attributes between your sub-classes.

If you intend to avoid 1:1 relationships, you'll have to create, for example, an `ServiceId` column and do the relationship with it, using `Id` as PK of `RoomService`. By the way, there is no problems with 1:1 relationships, specially in your case, where you are creating specialized sub-classes.

In addition, the `type` column will be used by your application to determine which subclass the object is. Also no problem on that.